# How can I filter a substring from a pandas dataframe based on a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I know this is a question that has been asked times and again but I'm not very good with list comprehensions and there a small twist to my code.

I have a dataframe containing keywords, I'd like to filter them if the keywords contain one or more keywords from a dedicated list.

Please note that I'm not looking for the exact expression, just the occurrence of a substring in the dataframe.

Basically I think it should look something like this :

```
substring_list = ['abc', 'def']
df[df['tag'].str.contains(substring) for substring in substring_list]
```

I keep getting syntax errors.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for the support !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas does binary filtering, so it returns a list of True / False corresponding to whether or not the string contains your key, you could just do bit wise anding / oring of all the conditions and hence you could get the strings that contains all your substrings or any of them (depending on whether you use 'and' & or 'or' | )

```
df[df['tag'].str.contains('abc') | df['tag'].str.contains('def')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df['tag'].str.contains('|'.join(substring_list))
```

Comment: @ Franco Piccolo, is good in list comprehension :-) i see

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this:

Use pattern base search by constructing the regex by joining the words in pattern with `|` as follows:

```
df[df.tag.str.contains('|'.join(substring_list))]
```

In case you have only few  strings to search then simple can use like below:

```
df[df.tag.str.contains("abc|def")]
```

**Example illustration:**

```
>>> df
   tag
0  abc
1  edf
2  abc
3  def
4  efg

>>> df[df.tag.str.contains("abc|def")]
   tag
0  abc
2  abc
3  def

>>> substring_list = ['abc', 'def']


>>> df[df.tag.str.contains('|'.join(substring_list))]
   tag
0  abc
2  abc
3  def
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works like a charm.

Comment: @sovnheim,   Welcome and glad it helped, i have added the example code, if you like the answer you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Just did. Thanks for reminding me and thanks again for the help.

Comment: @sovnheim, if you like the answer you can always upvote.